# Парсинг новостей Python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

уважаемые пользователи.

Решил изучить тему с парсингом сайтов, но достаточно быстро столкнулся с одной проблемой. Если кратко, то есть новостной сайт - news.ru, и обновление новостей на нём происходит через кнопку, привязанную к *ссылке-якорю html*.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из этого вытекает вопрос - как обновить раздел новостей, для дальнейшего парсинга, используя библиотеку *requests* и *bs4*.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: открываете вкладку Network и смотрите запросы, которые отправляются при нажатии на "Другие новости"